# Fill combobox with color of the cell?

Tags: excel

I have a question for you Stackers... How can I fill a comboox with the cell value and also with the cell color?

Let me be clear here is an example

[image]

As far as you can see, my **ListFillRange is A4:A9** that means that also the cells with **RED** and **GREEN** are also in my range, but when I click on my **ComboBox1** I don't see the colors, I just see a blank space..

Any Ideas?

Comment: Hi, you're not the first with this issue, but unfortunately what you're requesting cannot be done in a combobox. The dropdown list can have one background colour and that's it. There is a [workaround using a userform](https://www.ozgrid.com/forum/forum/help-forums/excel-general/92863-combobox-list-56-colors). But that might not be what you are looking for. Alternatively you can read out the colour and have it display as text, but it still wouldn't show the colour.

Comment: Yeah, Im working on a workaround btw, strange there were no people to answer my post. Thanks for your time! +1

Comment: No problem, sorry I couldn't help more. Also I'm sure other people have tried and came to the same conclusion as me. No need for them to duplicate the answer.